# How to install mapmap on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, repository

I tried to install mapmap (projection maping software) on Ubuntu 20.04 in this link
https://mapmapteam.github.io/
But when I execute commands, I get this error
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mapmap/mapmap/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.

and when i trying:
sudo apt-get install mapamp

I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package mapamp
```

So, that there any way for resolving this issue or is there any software like that for Ubuntu?

Comment: This is quite old software the ppa is dated at newest 2019. I do not see one for 20.04

Comment: Look at the last updates date top right. https://launchpad.net/~mapmap/+archive/ubuntu/mapmap

Comment: did you add the PPA top your system [as outlined](https://launchpad.net/~mapmap/+archive/ubuntu/mapmap)? You don't indicate which commands you  executed.

Comment: did you enter the correct command "E: Unable to locate package mapamp" Did you type mapamp as opposed to mapmap?

Answer (score 0):

The PPA has not seen an update since February of 2017. If you want to install via an apt package, you will need to use 14.04, which is EOL, or 16.04, which will be EOL in a little over a month. Looking at [the GitHub repository for the project](https://github.com/mapmapteam/mapmap), it seems to be primarily focused on macOS, though you *may* be able to compile it from source if you’re willing to debug. I say this last bit because the build status appears suspect:

[image: GitHub Build Status]

If you would like to give compiling a try, [the instructions can be found here](https://github.com/mapmapteam/mapmap/blob/develop/INSTALL.md).

Good luck

Comment: has any software like mapmap for ubuntu?

Comment: None that I’m aware of. There used to be [Splash](http://projection-mapping.org/splash/), but the project went [commercial](https://lightform.com/) many years ago and Linux support was dropped in favour of Windows. Looks like an opportunity if you’re interested in the area 

Comment: can i do this job with belender?

Answer (score 0):

Really you have two options:

- Download MapMap deb-package from the mentioned PPA and install it:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget https://launchpad.net/~mapmap/+archive/ubuntu/mapmap/+files/mapmap_0.5.0-2~xenial~ppa1_amd64.deb
  sudo apt-get install ./mapmap_0.5.0-2~xenial~ppa1_amd64.deb
  ```
- Clone source code of newest MapMap code and compile it:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install git
  cd ~/Downloads
  git clone https://github.com/mapmapteam/mapmap.git
  cd mapmap

  sudo apt-get install -y liblo-dev liblo-tools qttools5-dev-tools \
  qtmultimedia5-dev libqt5opengl5-dev qtwebengine5-dev \
  libqt5multimedia5-plugins qt5-default

  sudo apt-get install -y libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-vaapi \
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps \
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-x \
  gstreamer1.0-tools

  qmake mapmap.pro
  make
  ```

  then run it with

  ```
  ./mapmap
  ```